# swagger autogenerate schema for a custom validation annotation

Tags: swagger, openapi, micronaut

I created a custom validation annotation which is similar to `@javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`. For `@Pattern`, swagger generates a nice schema like this:

```
   summary: my summary
   operationId: my_operation_id
   parameters:
   - name: myParam
     in: header
     required: true
     schema:
       maxLength: 30
       pattern: ^\w+$ <--- THIS ONE
       type: string
```

But for my annotation `@CustomPattern` (let's say), it doesn't! The generated swagger.yml does not have `pattern` key under `schema`. How can I create one?

This is in Micronaut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to have swagger.yml generated for my controller methods' parameters.

Just stick in a `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema` annotation with `pattern` attribute. Or if it's a List, then you could use `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(pattern = ?))`

That will do.